# Angular Data Model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I defined a model for controller to encapsulate the model’s methods and operations based on [this](http://www.webdeveasy.com/angularjs-data-model/) article.

When i'm using prototype method to retrieve data, $http request are handled but data can not manipulate for using. Also I can't use it on view in no way. Angular error is:

> "TypeError: a is not a function".

I'm using angular v1.3.15 .

Example:

```
clientManager.getItem(id).then(
    function(res) {
        console.log(res.getUserData());
    }
);
```

Above error is for res.getUserData(). getUserData method is a method ike getImageUrl() on below  Book factory.

```
app.factory('Book', ['$http', function($http) {  
    function Book(bookData) {
        if (bookData) {
            this.setData(bookData):
        }
        // Some other initializations related to book
    };
    Book.prototype = {
        setData: function(bookData) {
            angular.extend(this, bookData);
        },
        getImageUrl: function(width, height) {
            return 'our/image/service/' + this.book.id + '/width/height';
        }
    };
    return Book;
}]);
```

How can I register prototype methods to my views?

Answer (score 0):

You never use $http service in this example. But res variable probably is default promise object, and no have this function getUserData.

Answer (score 0):

You don't register methods to views.

You now have a service which can be injected into controllers, directives or other services. So, if you need the book data in a view, you can inject the service into the view's controller:

```
   app.controller('ViewCtrl',  ['$scope','Book', function($scope, Book){
      var aBook = new Book();
      aBook.setData({'title':'value'});
      $scope.title = aBook.title;

    }])
```

The properties on the $scope are available in the view. So you can have something like {{title}} in your view